# how can i estimate the radii of an ellipse from point cloud?

Tags: python, pandas, geometry

I have a set of data points in a pandas data frame as shown in this image

[image: this image]

lets assume that the shape is that of a room. My goal is to determine which point belongs to the body of the room itself (wall and roof) and which point corresponds to an object held inside it.
since i don't have the exact dimensions of the room, i want to determine a radius for the ellipse and compare every point with them like so: `(x/rx)^2 + (y/ry)^2 <= 1` .
Can I estimate the major and minor radius of the outermost ellipse? how can I negate the impact of the few points that are outside the room itself? treating them as outliers didn't work since they're not that far from the other points.

i wrote this function but it's output is affected by the outer points.

```
def find_radi(df):
rx_points = df.loc[(df['y'] > -1) & (df['y'] < 1)]
ry_points = df.loc[(df['x'] > -1) & (df['x'] < 1)]
hist_rx = plt.hist(rx_points['x'])
hist_ry = plt.hist(ry_points['y'])
rx = (max(hist_rx[1]) + abs(min(hist_rx[1]))) /2
ry = (max(hist_ry[1]) + abs(min(hist_ry[1]))) /2
return rx, ry
```

Comment: This is a optimization problem where you are looking for the smallest ellipse that can fit all the relevant points inside. What I would do is to formulate an equation that is `rx + ry + alpha*penalty` and try to minimize that with a nonlinear solver like `scipy.optimize.minimize`. You need sendible beginning guesses for `rx`,  `ry` and `alpha`. The penalty can be calculated as number of points outside the ellipse or the sum of distances of points outside it. The `alpha` is a small number that makes the penalty to good order of magnitude.

Comment: And if you don't need to be scientific, just eyeball the radiuses from the figure, and draw different ellipses and select the one that fits best to your eye :)

Comment: Alternatively you could minimize the `area_of_ellipse + alpha*penalty` which is slightly better as it weights the two ellipse axis correctly.

Comment: See <https://docs.mosek.com/latest/pythonfusion/case-studies-ellipsoids.html>.

Comment: Can you share the coordinates, please? Thanks.

Comment: @blunova here you go https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vT4g8NtVahTlMhYMftD1bmgq-oFxMloXUboblZquB2xS2G-s7ltRRCjRYUFpZ6juQ/pubhtml.